# "gcloud builds submit" is not triggering error for missing required substitutions

Tags: google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I need some help with cloud build `--substitutions`.

This is the doc: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#substitutions

Here is what is says:

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
substitutions:
    _SUB_VALUE: world
options:
    substitution_option: 'ALLOW_LOOSE'
```

> The following snippet uses substitutions to print "hello world." The `ALLOW_LOOSE` substitution option is set, which means the **build will not return an error if there's a missing substitution** variable or a missing substitution.

My case: I'm NOT using the `ALLOW_LOOSE` option. I need my substitutions to be required. I don't want any default values being applied. And I need it to fail immediately if I forget to pass any of the substitutions that I need.

Here is my `cloudbuild.yaml` file:

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
substitutions: 
  _SERVER_ENV: required
  _TAG_NAME: required
  _MIN_INSTANCES: required
```

I'm initializing their default value as `required` specifically because I'm expecting the build call to fail if I forget to pass any of them to the `gcloud builds submit` call.

I'm expecting it to fail if I call `gcloud builds submit` and don't pass any of the defined substitutions. But it's not failing and the build completes normally without that value.

There is this observation in the docs:

> Note: **If your build is invoked by a trigger, the ALLOW_LOOSE option is set by default.** In this case, your build will not return an error if there is a missing substitution variable or a missing substitution. You cannot override the ALLOW_LOOSE option for builds invoked by triggers.

But if I'm calling `gcloud builds submit` manually, that means that my build is not being invoked by any triggers, right? So the `ALLOW_LOOSE` options shouldn't be enabled.

Here is my full `cloudbuild.yaml`:

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args:
      - "build"
      - "--build-arg" 
      - "SERVER_ENV=$_SERVER_ENV"
      - "--tag"
      - "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/server:$_TAG_NAME"
      - "."
    timeout: 180s

  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args:
      - "push"
      - "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/server:$_TAG_NAME"
    timeout: 180s

  - name: "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk"
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
      - "beta"
      - "run"
      - "deploy"
      - "server"
      - "--image=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/server:$_TAG_NAME"
      - "--platform=managed"
      - "--region=us-central1"
      - "--min-instances=$_MIN_INSTANCES"
      - "--max-instances=3"
      - "--allow-unauthenticated"
    timeout: 180s

images: 
  - "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/server:$_TAG_NAME"
substitutions: 
  _SERVER_ENV: required
  _TAG_NAME: required
  _MIN_INSTANCES: required
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `cloudbuild.yaml` file, when you define a `substituions` variable you automatically set his default value

```
substitutions: 
  # Value = "required"
  _SERVER_ENV: required 
  # Value = ""
  _TAG_NAME:
```

Try to use a variable that is not defined in the `substitutions` array, such as:

```
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk"
    entrypoint: bash 
    args:
      - -c
      - | 
         # print "required"
         echo $_SERVER_ENV 
         # print nothing
         echo $_TAG_NAME
         # Error, except if you allow loose. In this case, print nothing
         echo $_MIN_INSTANCES
substitutions: 
  _SERVER_ENV: required
  _TAG_NAME:
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I thought at first. But I've tried removing the `_SERVER_ENV` from the `subtitutions` property (it's not an array) and the same happens. I'll try to add the `substitution_option: "MUST_MATCH"` and see how it goes. Just found out about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#substitutionoption).

Comment: I'm starting to be pretty sure that this is a bug. That didn't work either. I removed the `substitutions` property completely. And didn't pass any of the expected `substitutions`. The build failed, but not because the `substitutions` where missing from the `gcloud builds submit` call, but because their missing values broke the steps that were relying on them being populated.

Comment: What!! I just tried and you are right, no error!!! Few weeks ago I got errors.... Agree, it should be a bug.

Comment: No luck with the PM. I opened this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178013730